# jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery is not defined
```

When I try to edit a post, rearange categories the "jQuery is not defined" keeps poping up in firebug. But If I change my theme to another it allows me to change the categories and stuff like that. I checked my functions.php there is no line about jquery...

Comment: Can you provide a link to the theme you are using?

Answer (score 2):

As you have pointed out; the problem fixes itself if you change to another theme. That says to me that your current theme is stopping jquery from loading, hence why you are getting jQuery is not defined.

Look in your theme files and make sure you don't have something like this: `wp_deregister_script('jquery');`. You should never de-register it from the admin. If you want to de-register jquery on the front end but not the admin screen then use something like this

```
if(!is_admin()) {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found out that I was deregistering then registering the new jquery 1.6 but I didn't enqueue it :). Thats why the Wordpress broke. Thank you for your help again!

Comment: @Zenger - that wouldn't cause it. If you post up your theme functions file somewhere we can maybe take a look and see if there is anything left to cause jquery from not loading. Also have you got any code in your theme header that might be causing issue? I take it that this is you own theme?